# Spacing problem with \phantom in array

Tags: spacing

Using

```
$\begin{array}{ccc}
x & := & \phantom{ a + } b + c\\
y & := & a \phantom{ + b } + c\\
z & := & a + b \phantom{ + c }
\end{array}$
```

I get

[image: some not quite beautiful equation array]

which is not quite what I hoped for as my "phantoms" don't take as much space as expected.

```
How can I correct this?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the final part of the first row, try `\phantom{a+{}}b+c` to make the first plus sign act like a "real" math-binary element. Similarly, you'll also need to adjust the second row to `a\phantom{{}+b}+c`.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that I added to my post to provide code for the second line.

Comment: Seeing the first line, I was able to guess the 2nd line. Thanks again!

Comment: @jug: I guess you then also figured out how to modify the 3rd line! :-)